# Too many PropertyHashMap and SpillProperty instances when use nashorn

Tags: java, jvm, nashorn

I use nashorn with jdk1.8, then run it. I found that the GC happened frequently. I get the instances count by `jmap -histo PID`, there are too many instances of `PropertyHashMap$Element` and `SpillProperty`:

java:

```java
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

jmap -histo:

```sh
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        923913      169207440  [C
   2:        864617       27667744  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyHashMap$Element
   3:        917296       22015104  java.lang.String
   4:        350381       19621336  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.SpillProperty
```

And question 2 of the same program, the cmd `jmap –heap PID` shows that both From Space and To Space are 0% used, but my jvm args is `--XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10`, is this OK?

```
Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space): 
    capacity = 1207959552 (1152.OMB) 
    used = 348986376 (332.81934356689453MB) 
    free = 858973176 (819.18065643310SSHB) 
    28.890568017959595% used
Eden Space:
    capacity = 1073741824 (1024.0MB) 
    used = 348986376 (332.81934356689453MB) 
    free = 724755448 (691.18065643310SSHB) 
    32.501889020204544% used
From Space:
    capacity = 134217728 (128.0MB)
    used =0 (0.0MB) 
    free = 134217728 (128.0MB)
    0.0% used
To Space:
    capacity = 134217728 (128.0MB)
    used =0 (0.0MB) 
    free = 134217728(128.0MB)
    0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation: 
    capacity = 268435456 (256.0MB) 
    used = 268434736 (255.9993133S44922HB) 
    free = 720 (6.8664SS07812SE-4HB) 
    99.99973177909851% used
```